# Read const value from int** initialized from int[][]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My goal is to access `max_resources_per_client[1][1]`.

In `conf.c` that can't be modified, I got:

```
#define NUM_CLIENTS 5
#define NUM_RESOURCES 3
const unsigned int num_clients = NUM_CLIENTS;
const unsigned int num_resources = NUM_RESOURCES;
const unsigned int max_resources_per_client[NUM_CLIENTS][NUM_RESOURCES] = {
  {7, 5, 3},
  {3, 2, 2},
  {9, 1, 2},
  {2, 2, 2},
  {4, 3, 3},
};
```

In my file `main.c` I have:

```
extern const unsigned int num_clients;
extern const unsigned int num_resources;
extern const unsigned int **max_resources_per_client;
```

How can I access `max_resources_per_client[1][1]` without causing a segmentation fault?

---

Note: Trying to do

`extern const unsigned int max_resources_per_client[num_clients][num_resources];`

results in an error: `variably modified ‘max_resources_per_client’ at file scope`

---

Note: Trying to do `extern const unsigned int max_resources_per_client[NUM_CLIENTS][NUM_RESOURCES];`

results in error: `NUM_RESOURCES’ undeclared here (not in a function)`

Comment: `const unsigned int **max_resources_per_client` type mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_resources_per_client` is a two-dimensional array of unsigned ints, which is different than `unsigned int **` (pointer to pointer to unsigned int). The extern declaration needs to declare `max_resources_per_client` as an array. The extern declaration should look like the definition in conf.c but without the initializer:

```
const unsigned int max_resources_per_client[NUM_CLIENTS][NUM_RESOURCES];
```

You actually don't need NUM_CLIENTS in order for the compiler to know what's going on, so you could declare it like this:

```
const unsigned int max_resources_per_client[][NUM_RESOURCES];
```

The compiler at least needs to know the second dimension so it can calculate the correct offset into the array. The above declaration tells it that each "row" of the array contains `NUM_RESOURCES` unsigned ints, which allows it to calculate the offset of any element.

Comment: How can I access NUM_RESOURCES defined in `config.c` from file `main.c`? Note: There is no `config.h`.

Comment: Ideally, `NUM_RESOURCES`would be in a .h file (along with the extern declarations). You can't use that array without knowing that dimension. Do you have any flexibility in rearranging this code?

Comment: The code in your "update" only works if the array definintion is also changed to `const unsigned int max_resources_per_client[NUM_RESOURCES * NUM_CLIENTS];`   .  With the original definition it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's a total hack and I don't recommend using it, but of course it works. The two-dimensional array as declared is 15 consecutive unsigned ints. We know exactly how it's laid out in memory, so having the compiler treat it as a one-dimensional array and doing the indexing manually will produce the correct result. In what situation would that not work? (I debated posting that solution because it's not clean, but it does work. Would it have been better to not post it?)

Comment: @AndySchweig One of the outcomes of undefined behavior is seemingly correct execution. I suggest you remove the invalid example.

Comment: Agreed. I removed it. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this -> [How to declare extern 2d-array in header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581574/how-to-declare-extern-2d-array-in-header)

You need, at a minimum, to include the right-most column size for a 2-D array. You can declare it like this:

```
extern unsigned char LCD[][64];
```

Otherwise the compiler would not be able to compute the offset after the first row.

Comment: For documentation purposes, it is in general better to define all dimensions.